# Retrieve all posts from the post_type on multisite WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, multisite

I'm using [switch_to_blog](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/switch_to_blog) to get all the posts from the blog_id. Is it possible to get all posts from other sites?
Also I've tried to use foreach as mention on the codex documentation.

This is what I've tried...

```
global $wpdb, $paged, $blog_id;

$site_blog_ids = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT blog_id FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."blogs where blog_id > 1")); // get all subsite blog ids

foreach($site_blog_ids as $bids){
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($bids->blog_id);
    echo '</pre>';
    switch_to_blog($bids->blog_id);
    restore_current_blog();
}

$video_args = array ( 
    'post_type' => 'video',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1, 
    'paged' => $paged,
);

 $video_query = new WP_Query( $video_args );
```

but still no luck..

Answer (score 0):

I get it. I just need to insert my WP_Query on foreach..

```
global $wpdb, $paged, $blog_id;

$site_blog_ids = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT blog_id FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."blogs where blog_id > 1")); // get all subsite blog ids

foreach($site_blog_ids as $bids) {
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($bids->blog_id);
    echo '</pre>';
    switch_to_blog($bids->blog_id);
    restore_current_blog();

$video_args = array ( 
    'post_type' => 'video',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1, 
    'paged' => $paged,
);

$video_query = new WP_Query( $video_args );

}
```